# Reading dynamically created file inside /proc/sys

Tags: c, linux, sysctl

LKM can create dynamically entries inside `/proc/sys`, but `sysctl` (not the Linux command but C's `sysctl`) accepts as first argument an array of ints with predefined values representing entries inside `/proc/sys`. My question is: can I read a dynamically created entry with `sysctl` or do I need to use `fopen`, `read`, etc...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the file system interface: `fopen`, `fread`, etc (or `open`, `read`, if you prefer).

And about the C function called `sysctl`, **[don't use it](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sysctl)**:

> Use of this system call has long been discouraged, and it is so unloved that **it is likely to disappear in a future kernel version**. Since Linux 2.6.24, uses of this system call result in warnings in the kernel log. Remove it from your programs now; use the `/proc/sys` interface instead.

Comment: Also, most of the pseudo-files in `/proc` are not seekable and should be read sequentially.